# Fatal error: Class 'Zend_View_Helper_Placeholder_Container_Abstract' not found in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Zend\View\Helper\Placeholder\Container.php

Tags: php, zend-framework

I had a problem with zend library. I am using php 5.2.4 and xampp 1.6.4. I am getting the error below. Here I am using windows 8.

```
Fatal error: Class 'Zend_View_Helper_Placeholder_Container_Abstract' not found 
in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Zend\View\Helper\Placeholder\Container.php on line 34.
```

Is there any thing that I need to set. I have tried with latest version zend also. But same error.

When I work with windows 7. It is fine.

Comment: check zf folder permissions

Comment: Where can i check zf folder permissions.Is it right click->properties and Security in windows or any other thing.

Comment: Does the file `C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Zend\View\Helper\Placeholder\Container\Abstract.php` exist?

Comment: Hi, I have updated my php version(xampp).It resolved the issue.